# JS function not working inside jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

myFunction123 isnt running when its inside the other jQuery function. How do I solve it?

```js
function myFunction123() {
  alert("Hello World!");
}

myFunction123(); // This works

document.querySelector(`#${HOME_GROUP} .what-you-can-do-btn`).addEventListener('click', () => {
  myFunction123(); // This does not
});
```

Comment: Let's debug it. How can you verify that your event listener is being called? Maybe add a console.log statement inside of it? Perhaps your query selector is not finding the element.

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong with your selector.

I tried:

```
function myFunction123() {
   alert("Hello World!");
}

myFunction123(); // works

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () => {
   myFunction123();
});
```

and it works. So that means `document.querySelector(`#${HOME_GROUP} .what-you-can-do-btn`)` probably returns `undefined`

Try to select element by ID only like `document.querySelector('#yourId')`

Answer (score 0):

First you must wait for Dom to load since you are attaching event listener to Dom objects.
Then using convenient selector with jQuery attach the listener using

$({selector})
where selector can be id using {#} selector 
`$('#id-of-element')` or 
class using dot selector - `$('.class-of-element')`.

If you happen to be passing a reference to a function like in the code below you do not need parenthesis since the event itself will invoke the function.
e.g. [`$('#hey').on('click', clickHandler)`] in your case [`domElement.addEventListener('click', myFunction123);`]

Complete Example:

```
//Function that handles the event
function clickHandler(){
  console.log('hey');
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  //Id Selector using jQuery
  $('#hey').on('click', clickHandler);

  //Class Selector using jQuery
  $('.what-you-can-do-btn').on('click', clickHandler)

})
```